# Getting 404 When page exists

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am using Java Servlets, JSPs, and Filters to return web pages and continuously get a 404 error when entering the following urls:

> www.mysite.com/download/
>   www.mysite.com/store/

When logging incoming requests to the filter, I never see either of these requests using the following code:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());
```

However, I see all other incoming request.  What am I missing?

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>MainController</filter-name>
    <filter-class>XXX.controller.MainController</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
        <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>XXX.security.XSSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MainController</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>XXXControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>XXX.controller.XXXControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error/Comp.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/XXXControllerServlet/*</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>404</exception-type>
        <location>/XXXControllerServlet/*</location>
    </error-page>
```

Comment: post your web.xml code

Comment: i just added the web.xml file.  Changes to this file still result in a 404 error.

Comment: post XSSFilter code

Comment: I removed it and still am getting this error.